# Number of integral values $\big(f'(x)\big)^2$ can take?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

For a twice differentiable function $f(x)$, we have $\big|f(x)\big|\leq 3 \;\forall \; x \in \mathbb R$ and for some $\alpha$, we have $f(\alpha)+\bigl(f'(\alpha)\bigr)^2=80$. Find the number of integral values $\big(f'(x)\big)^2$ can take in $(0,77).$

Now I used Lagrange's Mean Value theorem that there exists $c\in(0,3)$ such that $\big|f'(c)\big|=\bigg|\frac{f(3)-f(0)}{3-0}\bigg|$. Now as $\big|f(x)\big|\leq 3 \;\forall \; x \in R$, hence maximum value of $\big|f(3)-f(0)\big|$ can be 6, hence $\big|f'(c)\big|\leq2$ but I am not able to use information $f(\alpha)+\bigl(f'(\alpha)\bigr)^2=80$. How to proceed in this. Given answer is $76$.

Comment: First sentence : "for every function" ???  You surely mean : "Let us consider a (particular) function $f$ such that..."

Comment: What do you mean by "find the number of integral values..."?

Answer (score 10):

The interval $(0,77)$ has $76$ integer values, so $(f’(x))^2$ can take at most $76$ integer values. We claim that all these values are taken by $(f’(x))^2$. Indeed, by Lagrange’s theorem there exists $\beta\in (0,7)$ such that $\frac{f(7)-f(0)}{7-0}=f’(\beta)$. Then $(f’(\beta))^2<1$. Since $(f’(\alpha))^2\ge 80-f(\alpha)\ge 77$, by the intermediate value theorem, $(f’(x))^2$ takes all values from $(f’(\beta))^2$ to $77$.